# Why are coordinate processes introduced?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-process

I don't fully understand what a coordinate process is and why they are used. My lecture notes say the following:

> For an arbitrary measurable space $(S,\mathcal{S})$ we denote by $S^{[0,\infty)}$ the space of all functions $y: [0,\infty)\to S,t\mapsto y(t)$. We introduce the coordinate process $Y = (Y_t)_{t\geq 0}$ on $S^{[0,\infty)}$ by setting $Y_{t}(y):=y(t)$ for $y\in S^{[0,\infty)}$ and $t\geq 0$.

1. So we have a random process $Y$ on the spaces of all functions on $S$ and the $t$-position for some function $y$ of this process is equal to $y(t)$. What exactly is the point here, why do we need to introduce this? Does this mean when we show properties for this process $Y$, we automatically show them for any other stochastic process, such as RCLL processes?
2. Also my notes talk about $Y$ being the canonical $\mathbb{P}_{\nu}$-Markov process (for some transition semigroup $(K_t)_{t\geq 0}$ and initial distribution $\nu$ on $(S,\mathcal{S})$). What exactly does 'canonical process' mean?

Comment: One thing. You wrote "the $t$-position of this process is equal to an arbitrary function...", but that's not the right interpretation. You mis-wrote the equation for the coordinate process, it should be $Y_t(y) := y(t)$. What this says is that the $t$-position of the process is a functional on the space $S^{[0,\infty)}$ which inputs $y \in S^{[0,\infty)}$ and outputs the value of $y$ at time $t$, namely $y(t)$.

Comment: @LeeMosher Thank you for pointing this out. I still don't see why we use this process.

Comment: I believe canonical process means the process built on the "natural" choice of space. On a given sample path, canonical process means  $Y_t(y) = y(t)$. In this case, the natural choice is the space of all functions. For example, see the comment on page 60 here: http://www.science.unitn.it/~tubaro/corso3/KS.pdf
about the canonical space of a Brownian motion is the set of continuous functions but it can be built on other sample spaces.